# Jquery disabling a keyboard key

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to disable a certain keyboard key (like asterisk or string) by using jquery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't disable a key stroke as such but you could capture it with jQuery and overwrite its action (return false). The example below captures the enter key. Just change 13 to any key code you need to disable.

```
$("input").keypress(function (evt) {

  var keycode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
  if (keycode  == 13) { //Enter key's keycode
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Just realised that would capture on input fields. If you want to disable across a page change "input" to "body".

Answer (score 6):

I had to disable all the keys but the F11 and ESC. So I did this way. Think this may help someone. :)

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e)
{ 
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
    if(key == 122 || key == 27 )
        {}
    else
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: its helpfull but its not working on PrtSc screen , actully i want to use this on no one can save my page even not screenshot, if u can plz help

Answer (score 1):

Handle `onKeyDown`, then `preventDefault` on it.

Answer (score 1):

i can think of something like this:

```
// Bind this keypress function to the html (not sure about this) or body tags of your page
$("body").keypress(function (evt) {
//Determine where the character code is coming from
var charCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;

if (charCode  == 13) { //Enter key's keycode, could be any other key
return false;
}
});
```

by returning false you are telling the browser to not allow the key pressed event

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `OnKeyUp,Down-EventListener` to your HTML Page and if the pressed key is that you want to ignore you just `preventDefault`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following plugin like this :
`$('#text_input').filter_input({regex:'[a-z]'})`;

http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input