# Disbaling CTRL+S problems

Tags: javascript

By disbaling the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> I am unable to write anything all my keypress and keydown events are blocked. Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown keypress', 'ctrl+s', function() { 
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Well, then don't do it! To be serious: you're not disabling CTRL+S, you're _disabling_ every key. Please check jQuery .bind() syntax.

Comment: [jQuery disabling a keyboard key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805137/jquery-disabling-a-keyboard-key)

Comment: so what i do to disable ctrl+s function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This catches <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on OSX) and stops it from being processed:

```js
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', function(evt) { 
  var modifier = navigator.platform == "MacIntel" ? evt.metaKey : evt.ctrlKey;
  if (modifier && evt.which == 83) return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

However, it doesn't stop File -> Save As... and even when it works, users are typically annoyed if you change how their software works. If I come to your page and run into this issue, I will not come again unless forced to. I suggest you only do this after very careful risk-benefit analysis.